# Bad request while trying to access Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to access to a `Sharepoint site` from my WebApp but I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code

Code:

```
public void ReadSharepointProperties()
{
    try
    {
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(_siteURL))
        {
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

`_siteURL` is correct. At least I can access it.

Any idea?

**.NET core 2.0.5**

*EDIT:*

More info: I see in the debug the call changes to "url.../_vti_bin/sites.asmx"

I tried to do like in the link http://rajujoseph.com/getting-net-core-and-sharepoint-csom-play-nice/ and now the error is different:

> One or more errors occurred. (Cannot find platform service library.
>   For Windows Store application, please include
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.WindowsStore.dll in the
>   application package. For Windows Phone application, please include
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.WindowsPhone.dll in the
>   application package. For Windows application, please install
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows.dll in the GAC (Global
>   Assembly Cache) or make it available for the Windows application.)

Error is clear and the link tells how to solve it, but for console application. This case is for a ASP NET CORE, so it seems the dlls are no valid.

Comment: check [this](http://rajujoseph.com/getting-net-core-and-sharepoint-csom-play-nice/) and [this](http://www.sharepoint.bg/radi/post/Getting-Started-with-ASPNET-Core-Add-ins-for-SharePoint-Online). `.NET Core` is not currently supported with `CSOM`. There is a [uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16585795-support-net-core-with-csom) link for it as well.

Comment: @GautamSheth thanks for the links. I have done it, but now the error changed.
`One or more errors occurred. (Cannot find platform service library. For Windows Store application, please include Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.WindowsStore.dll in the application package. For Windows Phone application, please include Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.WindowsPhone.dll in the application package. For Windows application, please install Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows.dll in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) or make it available for the Windows application.)`

Answer (score 1):

Create a .NET Core console app.
Add the references: **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.dll**, **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable.dll** and **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows.dll**.

Then check if it works. 
As a workaround, we can also use REST API or web service in .NET Core application currently. Using REST API, we don't need reference those dlls in project.

**Get to know the SharePoint REST service**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service

Comment: I created the net core console app and it works. Problem is still present with a WebApp. how could be a solution using a rest api?

Comment: Check the official document about the REST API, we don't need reference the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.*dlls in the project using the REST API.

Comment: @LZ-SPWX, Are you getting the dlls from the Microsoft.Sharepointonline.CSOM Nuget package? The "windows" dll doesn't exist in the "netcore45" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you may have the URL incorrectly entered?

You should use "http://servername/" instead of "http://servername/sites/subfolder/default.aspx"

Comment: I have tried the `https://servername/` , `https://servername/sites/site/` and the `https://servername/sites/site/home.aspx`. None of them work.

Comment: If it's not the URL then my next concern would be security. Does the account that the WebApp is running under have permissions to SharePoint?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the credentials in the context. Do you know how can I pass the current Windows Authentication credentials of the logged user in the running site?

Comment: Not sure how you have things set up but if you are using IIS, maybe you can configure Windows authentication with the app and then run the code impersonating the current user. Here is a way to set it up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x